# Network Engineering — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

If you are one of the 72 users in the first two pages [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all), I have some great news for you!
We want to send you a token of our appreciation for helping this site and community grow healthily into what they are today! We're sending you a little box, inside which you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKERS!!!!!!!]

**A COOL KEY-CHAIN!**

[image: KEY-CHAIN!!!!!!!!!!]

I'll be reaching out to you later today with a link to a form: be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so! You'll have two weeks to do it, after which I'll close the form and take care of sending all of the swag your way! It should take from 6 to 8 weeks for the package to be delivered to you!

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such!

**Thanks to all of you for making this site great!**

<sub><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub>I'd add a UDP joke here, but you might not get it... ʱªʱªʱª (ᕑᗢूᓫ∗)</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sub>

Comment: Just a note: This is shipping out today!

Comment: Received mine this morning, great work @JNat!!!

Comment: Hmmm I was one of the first 72 users, but never got a package… is it too late ?

Comment: Unfortunately it is, @MikePennington — we no longer have per-site swag.

Answer (score 7):

Cool. Thanks JNat & Co. That is kind of you and the community to provide free swag to your users.

Answer (score 2):

Wow guys - very appreciated!  Keep up the great work with the site/community : )